# assigning a callback function to a variable

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am passing a callback function as below but I am not able to call this function when onreadystatechange changes it value i.e. request.onreadystatechange = func. I am getting a proper response from the server when I am calling the ajax request,but this method func is not getting called. Please note that func is passed as string when I call `getFromServer("http://localhost/ch02/checkName.php?username=sas","func")`

```
function createRequest() {
    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (failed) {
        request = null; }
    finally  {
        return request;
    }
}

function func(){
    alert("ok");
}

function getFromServer(url,readystateCallback) {
    request=createRequest();
    if (request == null) {
        alert("unable to create request");
    } else {
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        var func= new Function (readystateCallback);
        request.onreadystatechange = func;
        request.send(null);
    }
    return request;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use parenthesis here with readystateCallback. It should only get executed when request changes its state.

Comment: my bad, thats was a mistake, deleted the comment... I meant:
`request.onreadstatechange = readystateCallback`

Comment: Use an anonymous function:

`request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    //do something here - you can put a function call here.
  }`

What you are doing in your example is passing a string and then assigning the callback to a string value rather than making an actual function call.

Comment: yes, that is one way but I want to call this function by name only as I want the option to change the function name if I want in the argument passed to getFromServer function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is defined in the global scope, it will be added to the `window` object, so you can do:

```
var func = window[readystateCallback];
```

But rather than depending on this, you should make your own object that maps function names to functions. This way, you can access functions in a local scope, and you also can't inadvertently call some unexpected function as a callback.

```
function func() {
    alert("ok");
}
function otherfunc() {
    alert("really great");
}
...

var callbacks = {
    "func": func,
    "otherfunc": otherfunc,
    ...
}
```

Then you can do:

```
function getFromServer(url,readystateCallback) {
    request=createRequest();
    if (request == null) {
        alert("unable to create request");
    } else {
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        var func= callbacks[readystateCallback];
        request.onreadystatechange = func;
        request.send(null);
    }
    return request;
}
```

But the real, best solution is not to pass a function name in the first place. Just pass the function itself, this is how practically all Javascript interfaces that use callbacks work. So you should call it this way:

```
getFromServer("http://localhost/ch02/checkName.php?username=sas", func);
```

Then you simply do:

```
request.onreadystatechange = readystateCallback;
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that getFromServer is in my utilities library for commonly used functions. Callbacks won't have any idea as to what other name-value pairs it may require in future. Only the module in my current project knows the function name and the function itself is only defined in this project only. Any other project will have its own callback function.

Comment: Why are you passing function names as strings instead of the function itself?

Comment: I am passing function names as strings for readability. There must be some way to call the function from the string.

Comment: I showed how to do it in the first part of my answer.

Comment: Why is `getFromServer("http://localhost/ch02/checkName.php?username=sas","func")` more readable than `getFromServer("http://localhost/ch02/checkName.php?username=sas",func)`?

Comment: ok, I am accepting answer. Coming from java background, I am slowly getting used to handling functions as first class objects. Yours is good alternate solution.